# Qt Model Test, removeRows

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qt5, qtestlib

I have a tree model with internal structure similar to [Simple Tree Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html). There is a special array-type items, for which I want to display an index. My data method looks like this:

```
QVariant Model::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role ) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    TreeNode *item = getItem(index);

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return item->text();
    }
    ...

    return QVariant();
}

const QString TreeNode::text() const
{
    if (array) {
        return name() + " [" + QString::number(childNumber()) + "]";
    }
    return mText;
}
```

I have a unit test that performs node removal, which uses [Model Test](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/tests/auto/modeltest/modeltest.cpp). The problem occurs in the last line of this test

```
void ModelTest::rowsRemoved ( const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end )
{
    Changing c = remove.pop();
    QVERIFY( c.parent == parent );
    QVERIFY( c.oldSize - ( end - start + 1 ) == model->rowCount ( parent ) );
    QVERIFY( c.last == model->data ( model->index ( start - 1, 0, c.parent ) ) );
    QVERIFY( c.next == model->data ( model->index ( start, 0, c.parent ) ) );
}
```

which compares the value before removal with value after removal. In my case, since I also display indices, they don't match. For example, I had `Item1` and `Item2` in the model. If `Item1` is removed, then `Item2` becomes `Item1` and the test fails.

My question is is something wrong in my model implementation? Should I handle this situation differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in QAbstractItemModel cannot be just silently changed. You should always emit dataChanged signal for indexes which data has changed.

If you do this:

```
" [" + QString::number(childNumber()) + "]"
```

then you need to emit dataChanged signal each time childNumber() changed. So it would be much easier if index data could be changed only via QAbstractItemModel::setData.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. I wonder if that would be OK to `emit dataChange` between `beginRemoveRows` and `endRemoveRows`?

Comment: Yes, I already figured. I adjusted my model to change indices after removal.